# Swift uiscrollerview is not scrolling anything

Tags: swift

I have got this code:

```
var scrollView: UIScrollView!
            scrollView = UIScrollView(frame: self.view.bounds)
        scrollView.backgroundColor = .white
        scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width:self.view.frame.width,height:self.view.frame.height+1000)
        scrollView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight

        view.addSubview(scrollView)

        scrollView.addSubview(profileInfWrapper)
        scrollView.addSubview(PostsTab)
        scrollView.addSubview(FollowersTab)
        scrollView.addSubview(FollowingTab)
        scrollView.addSubview(AboutTab)
        scrollView.addSubview(collectionView)
```

But unfortunately this code is adding a scroller. But when it is scrolling, it doesn't change anything. All subvies of `scrollView` have constraints.

Comment: Are you using autolayouts?

Comment: @ManikantaChintapalli I don't have a storyboard,so no.

Comment: One "trick" is not to set contentSize just pin bottom anchor of the last view to the bottom anchor of the scrollView and this will automatically set its height

Comment: @Phyber i tried pinning `collectionView`'s bottom anchor to `scrollView`'s bottomAnchor,it didn't work

Comment: Can we move this discussion into [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150621/swift-uiscrollerview-is-not-scrolling-anything)

Comment: Once try scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true and see out put

Comment: @ManikantaChintapalli nothing different

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to enable scrolling.

```
scrollView.isScrollEnabled = true
```

Comment: scrollView.delegate  = self